# Rewriting C-expression using << and +

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, expression

How can I write following C expression using left-shift bit-wise operator (<<) and plus sign (+)?

```
y = x * 6;
```

Comment: x << 2 + x << 1

Comment: `x*6` is the same as `x*(4+2)` (powers of 2; 6 in binary) is the same as `x*4 + x*2`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why do you want to do this? Is this a homework question?

Comment: Just use the multiplication operator. Rewriting will make it less readable, and you won't understand the code tomorrow. Let the compiler decide the best way to multiply by 6. [The answer may surprise you](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Y7dv2-).

Comment: @Eraklon: `x << 2 + x << 1` will not work. That is `x << (2 + x) << 1`.

Comment: No this is not a homework question. It was a tutorial question, and I didn't get the explanation given so I asked here.

Comment: Also, for `x = 5`, `y = 5 * 6` gives 30, but `x << 1 + x << 2` gives 1280. Is it correct still?

Comment: @RaymondChen: The goal of tutorial demonstrations like these is not to find an optimal expression. The goals include teaching students how operators work and perhaps how to transform various expressions and otherwise work with them. Chiming in with “just” use something else is no more helpful than interrupting an elementary school class where students are learning to add numbers in columns and to carry from column to column with a recommendation that they just use a calculator. It is not helpful. The students need to learn the material, not to avoid it, even if a computer can do it for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x << n` means x * 2<sup>n</sup> by definiton (C18 §6.5.7/4). Knowing that x * 6 means x * 2 + x * 4, which is x * 2<sup>1</sup> + x * 2<sup>2</sup>, we can rewrite `y = x * 6;` as `y = (x << 1) + (x << 2);`.

Comment: Or `x+x+x+x+x+x << 0`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil technically, yes, practically, I doubt OP's teacher would like that solution.

Comment: Also, for `x = 5`, `y = 5 * 6` gives 30, but `x << 1 + x << 2` gives 1280. Is it correct still?

Comment: @user9854776 you're missing the parentheses:  `(x << 1) + (x << 2)`

Comment: @user9854776: 1280 is not 30. Therefore, that is not a correct replacement for `x * 6`.

Comment: No need to assume "two's complement arithmetic".

Comment: @pmg you need to assume some representation, right? We can't talk about no representation.

Comment: @Ayxan by definition, `val << n` is `val * (2^n)` whether on a regular computer, a decimal computer, a quantum computer, a Klingon computer,...